# AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume no longer functioning on 6+ devices

Tags: java, android

So I'm encountering a strange issue where calling `AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI)` no longer triggers a system volume change on the device I just updated to 6.0.

On all pre-6 devices this code works as expected. I did notice the changes to AudioManager where setStreamVolume has been deprecated, but the suggested alternative is what I was already using...

At first I believed it might be a permission issue since `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` is listed as a dangerous permission, but I've checked and `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` (and there's also no audio-related permissions in the Permission Settings page, so I'm assuming this isn't the case).

I've tried the other recommended method, `adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI)`, but that also yielded no results.

So, to clarify:

Nothing visually occurs when calling adjustStreamVolume/adjustVolume and `AudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)` returns the unchanged value as if it were never called.

If anyone has any thoughts on this, I would really love to hear them right about now.

Edit:

Since posting this, I've switched to using `setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, value, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI)` which works, even though the docs say it no longer should.

Would love some thoughts on this...

Edit 2:

Opened [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215908) since I was able to replicate on another device

Comment: In the docs about [AudioManager.setStreamVolume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) is nothing about it not working. There only is a comment about the Do Not Disturb mode.

I have no idea why `adjustStreamVolume` doesn't work though.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm referring to the note in the 6.0 changes: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-audiomanager-Changes

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's deprecated, shouldn't mean it should stop working. It's still supported for backward compatibility.

Make sure you get the correct handle for the AudioManager:

```
AudioManager audioManager =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Then, use this audioManager to set the Stream Volume for the desired value:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, desiredVolume, 0);
```

Comment: Hi Hazem, thanks for answering. Unfortunately the docs said it was no longer supported; not just deprecated, but apparently that's not the case (if you take a look at my edit) where setStreamVolume does work. However, the question is about why adjustStreamVolume does not since that's the one which is both recommended by the docs, but also currently not working on the 6+ devices I've tried

Comment: Well, it happens sometimes that no-longer-supported features get broken by time, because they no longer exist in their testing plans. So, if "adjust" doesn't work and "set" works, then you're stuck with "set" .. and pray that "set" remains to work in the future :)

Comment: Thanks again for responding, but that doesn't really answer the question since this is either a bug in the platform or an error in the documentation.